# Will a spinning disk spin longer if a radial object moves from the center to the rim of a spinning disk?

Tags: energy

Imagine a bicycle wheel level with the ground able to rotate around its center.  Centered on one of the wheel "spokes" is a heavy marble which can slide from the center of the wheel to rim of the wheel and vice-versa.  If the wheel is spun once very hard by hand, the marble will move from the center to the rim and return to the center as the wheel stops spinning.

Question:  Does the wheel spin longer with the heavy marble at the rim then if there was no marble on the spoke?

I suspect it does spin longer.

Please no formulas or highly technical discussion; a yes or no answer and a simple explanation would be appreciated.  Thank you for sharing your knowledge of physics.

Answer (score 1):

Without the extra mass confer

[spinning wheel with friction](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237811281_Friction_Modeling_of_a_Free-Spinning_Bicycle_Wheel/link/53d1d4220cf220632f3c4dce/download)

The primary source of dissipation of rotational energy is a torque in the axis by friction, that is constant independent of angular velocity for dry friction and proportional to angular velocity for viscous friction .

The second source is air resistance over all of the wheels area, growing with the third power of angular frequency, but becoming neglegible at low angular velocity.

Moving the addtional  mass from the center to the rim  changes kinetic energy if forces are applied (confer spinning ice dancer), and angular momentum, if torques are applied.

If e.g. the mass is fixed by a spring to the axis, part of energy  is stored as potential energy in the sping while moving to the rim, to be released  with  decreasing angular velocity.

The mass moved to the rim reduces the angular speed by increasing the moment of inertia by $m r^2$. But it is by no means clear, how to preserve energy in such an action, where radial kinetic energy is lost, if the mass is at rest ofter the move.

The dry friction makes a constant energy loss per round, the viscous friction per second, the air resistance decreases per round.

Now you can calculate the energy loss per round or per time as the solution of a Newtons differential equation with a constant torque $k$ and the total torque of the air resistance force integrated over the area of the wheel.

$$m r^2  \dot \omega = - T_{dry} - k_{viscous} \omega$$

with solution for start velocity $\omega(0) = \Omega$

$$\omega(t) = \frac{T}{k} \ \left(1-e^{-\frac{k t}{m r^2}}\right)\ + \ \Omega \  e^{-\frac{k t}{m r^2}}$$

upt to time

$$t< \frac{m r^2}{k}\log(1 +\frac{ k \Omega}{T})$$

when $\omega$ reaches zero.

Answer (score 0):

> If the wheel is spun once very hard by hand, the marble will move from the centre to the rim and return to the centre as the wheel stops spinning.

Why should the marble return to the centre ? If it does, this suggests that the spokes are not horizontal.

> Does the wheel spin longer with the heavy marble at the rim then if there was no marble on the spoke?

If you spin the wheel *at the same speed* with and without the marble then it will spin for longer with the marble than without, because while spinning at a given speed it has more energy with the marble than without. So if the spinning wheel loses energy to friction at a fixed rate then the higher its initial energy, the longer it will spin.

Comment: Now imagine a flat, circular disk with radial "spokes" slightly tilted downward toward the center. The "marble" is centered on the spoke and can move freely but returns to the center due to the slope of the spoke. Atop the disk are "blades" which catch wind and rotate the disk (VAWT). As the disk is moved circuitously by the wind, the marble moves toward the rim of the disk. The wind stops. The disk continues to spin. The "more energy/spin longer" is due to the marble rim position. If the marble was fixed at the disk center, would the energy be the same but spin less? No energy difference?

Comment: @JoeDoks If the marble is fixed at the centre  of the wheel then the wheel plus marble has a smaller moment of inertia than if the marble is at the rim. So if you spin the wheel *at the same speed* it has more energy if the marble is at the rim then if the marble is at the centre. So if the spinning wheel loses energy to friction at a fixed rate then the it will spin for longer if the marble is at the rim than if the marble is at the centre.